# Django suit unable to detect template override

Tags: django, django-templates, django-suit

I am overriding a template file in django-suit. Unfortunately this file is not detected and overridden.
According to their [documentation](http://django-suit.readthedocs.org/en/develop/#templates):

> Alternatively you can copy base_site.html to any of template
>   directories, which are defined in TEMPLATE_DIRS setting (if any). By
>   default Django looks in every registered application templates/ dir.

I have copied the file `base_site.html` into an existing `app/templates/admin` directory but this is not detected. I am already consuming template files from this directory so it should work.

What may be wrong in my situation?

Comment: check you context processors, the order is very important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your app is above suit in INSTALLED_APPS in settings file.

This is really important step to learn how template loaders work. It checks the folders in order of app in INSTALLED_APPS setting if it finds the template in first folder it uses that template. That's why also suit has to be above admin app because it overrides admin templates.